# Setting a different cache header per site-section in nginx

Tags: nginx, web-server, configuration, cache

For different website sections we use different caching headers. For example: the `/wp-admin` section shouldn't be cached at all, and the `/blog` section only for 4 hours instead of the default 2 days.

Currently I've solved this by repeating `location`-blocks, but that leads to quite a verbose file. Is there a more concise way to achieve this?

#### Example of current nginx configuration

```
location /wp-admin/ {
    etag off;
    if_modified_since off;
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}

location / {
    expires 2d;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}

location /blog {
    expires 4h;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this using standard NGINX configuration.

To tidy up your configuration (without using external tools) move the common configuration into its own file and include it from each section:

*php.conf*:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

*site.conf*:

```
location /wp-admin/ {
    etag off;
    if_modified_since off;
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;

    include php.conf;
}
```

NGINX is notorious for requiring lots of repetition for advanced configuration.